# apatía studio 3 download

Tags: aptana3

I'm trying to install Astana Studio 3 and I keep getting this message not sure what to do thanks

The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the correct version of Java:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US